# Attrs not evaluated when using "parent." notation on one2many's fields

Tags: xml, odoo

I assigned default value on stock.picking object in Action XML.

This default value will determine few condition on form behavior, includes i need to disable few fields on the lines (stock.move), but it's hard for me to do attrs on stock move fields as i can't use "parent" as notation.

For example i want to do something like this

```
<xpath expr="/form/notebook/page/field[@name='move_lines']/form/group/field[@name='location_dest_id']" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="attrs">{'readonly': [('parent.type','=','out')]}</attribute> 
</xpath>
```

NB : i can't use field.related, reason as in if i'm creating a new record there're no way field.related can get the default value i assigned on window actions.

Is there any way to do Attrs using parent default value as condition?

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is example, please try that one.

This `attrs` will make `readonly` when `Shipping Type = Sending Goods`

```
<field name="location_dest_id" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="attrs">{'required': [('chained_picking_type','=','out')]}</attribute>
</field>
```

**Generic Answer**

```
<field name="parent_id" position="attributes">
    <attribute name="attrs">{'required': [('parent_field_name','=','value_of_field')]}</attribute>
</field>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Well parent.type is 1 of my example, actually i need few conditions which requires to pull value from parent. Any suggestion?

Comment: Yes i'm also given a example.You can use above `attrs` also. for here `chained_picking_type` is a field of `Location.` Wait i will edit my answer and give you generic solution.

Comment: I mean is how if i want to disable Destination Location if field type on picking is 'out' & movement (the field i created) is 'ppp'

What should i write on attrs ?